# Event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem that I replicated in the little code snippet below (in the most simple way possible, however it still shows the problem I am facing).

Here is the snippet :

```js
const searchBar = document.getElementById('search');
const resBox = document.getElementById('results');

searchBar.addEventListener('input', function handler(e) {
    if (e.target.value === '') {
        resBox.innerHTML = '';
        return false;
    }
  
    setTimeout(() => populate(e), 300);
});

function populate(e) {  
    const btnBox = document.createElement('div');
  
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        const btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.classList.add('js-click')
        btn.innerText = 'Click me';
   
        btnBox.appendChild(btn);
    }
  
    resBox.appendChild(btnBox);
  
    dynamicBtnClickListener();
}


function dynamicBtnClickListener() {
    resBox.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
        console.log('You clicked me !');
    });
  
  // THE SOLUTION I FOUND FOR THE MOMENT :
  
  //const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button.js-click');
  //btns.forEach(btn => {
  //    btn.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
  //        console.log('You clicked me !');
  //    });
  //});
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="results"></div>
```

As you can see in the snippet, I have a first listener on input that generates a list of buttons when you type in it. When it is empty, the buttons disappear. In my real world case, it is a search input, that when a user types in, calls a function that populates a result box below it with results from DB.

I then have an on click listener on the buttons. In the code snippet, I simply put a console('You clicked me') when you click on the buttons. In my real app, it takes the result item (each result is an user) and inserts it in a table.

The problem appears when you open, close, then re-open the results box. This is done by inputing something, clearing the input, then re-input something. When you do that and then click on one of the buttons, it fires the click event on them as many times as you opened / closed the result box, so you will see the "You clicked me" on console multiple times.

I have done some research and most of it calls for using event.stopPropagation() and / or removing the event listener(s). I did try all these possible solutions, in every way I could think of, but I couldn't make it work.

Anyways I found a way around this (the commented portion of the dynamicBtnClickListener() function), but I feel it is not optimal. It consists of getting all the buttons with querySelectorAll(), then loop through them and add the click listener to every one of them, but I do not think it is optimal nor best-practice like. This is why I come here to ask if maybe there is a better solution, possibly one that keeps the click listener on the results box (if that is the most optimal solution. Is it by the way ?).

So even though I found a solution to this problem, could someone please tell me what is the best practice and optimal way of doing this ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: so on every input you add an event listener....\

Comment: @epascarello I do, while delaying the call of the populate() function with setTimeout

Comment: @epascarello Could you please go on with the idea behind your comment ? If there is a better way than having a listener on every input to do this kind of task, I would gladly like to know it. Thank you

Comment: You delay it.... you do not cancel it... simple console.log() inside of `dynamicBtnClickListener` will show it

Comment: @epascarello Could you please develop ? I feel you could learn me something important but I would likely need a more detailed explanations of the hows and whys. Do you mean using removeEventListener() on the input listener ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time the you type in the text area, `resBox` is accessed each time and the actual element `resBox` gets a new event listener every time(the buttons don't have any specific listener themselves, so I make **EACH BUTTON** have a specific listener *individually*)

```js
const searchBar = document.getElementById('search');
const resBox = document.getElementById('results');

searchBar.addEventListener('input', function handler(e) {
    if (e.target.value === '') {
    resBox.innerHTML = '';
    return false;
  }
  
    setTimeout(() => populate(e), 300);
});

function populate(e) {  
  const btnBox = document.createElement('div');
  
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.classList.add('js-click')
    btn.innerText = 'Click me';
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(ev){console.log('You clicked me !')})
    btnBox.appendChild(btn);
  }
  
  resBox.appendChild(btnBox);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="results"></div>
```

Now, here is an example that only has one event listener but would completely handle the situation >:D

Technically this should be faster(since one event listener compared to many), but **personally** I prefer this option because it *"feels better"* due to one function controlling the whole button layout(which would make it less *"rigid"*)

PS: The speed difference is so insignificant, you can pick and choose(but if a whole chuck ton of buttons, yea this becomes better)

```js
const searchBar = document.getElementById('search');
const resBox = document.getElementById('results');
const randChars=()=>{ //random characters to prove ONE event listener can work for multiple buttons in resBox
  let arr=["a","b","c","d","e"]
  let randIndex=()=>Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)||1
  let n=randIndex(); let returnChar=""
  for(let i=0;i<n;i++){returnChar+=arr[randIndex()]}
  return returnChar
}

searchBar.addEventListener('input', function handler(e) {
    if (e.target.value === '') {
    resBox.innerHTML = '';
    return false;
  }
  
    setTimeout(() => populate(e), 300);
});

resBox.addEventListener('click',function(ev){ //single event listener for all buttons
  let currentButton=ev.path[0]
  if(currentButton.tagName!="BUTTON"){return;} //if a button was not clicked
  console.log("Button with text\n'"+currentButton.innerText+"'\nwas clicked")
})

function populate(e) {  
  const btnBox = document.createElement('div');
  
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.classList.add('js-click')
    btn.innerText = 'Click me '+randChars();
    btnBox.appendChild(btn);
  }
  
  resBox.appendChild(btnBox);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, isn't it basically the same as the solution I found in dynamicBtnClickListener() (the commented part) ?

Comment: no it isnt, because it will add new listeners to buttons that **ALREADY EXIST**

Comment: But what is the difference between adding the listeners when creating the buttons and afterwards ? Is it performance-wise ? If so, shouldn't it be so minimal that not really worth thinking about it ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: let me explain.. let's say there are already 3 buttons existing.. and I use ur solution.. the first 3 buttons have **TWO** event listeners whereas the last 3 would have **ONE**. This is because that *"solution"* adds event listeners to every button each time(therefore buttons added before would get **EXTRA** event listeners). However, my function only adds **ONE** event listener to each button **ALONE**

Comment: I finally understand. Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate your help and the fact you took the time to explain this in depth. It is much more clear now and it will surely avoid me mistakes in the future.

Comment: @Tom687 btw should I add another snippet that can use buttons individually with just ONE GENERAL LISTENER?

Comment: That would be great ! If you could also explain the differences it makes and why it is or is not a better way to do it, and / or when it should be used or not, you would be the best !

Comment: Thanks man, you're a legend :D ! May I please ask you one more thing ? See the comments @epascarello wrote on the OP ? Would it be possible for you to explain a bit what he meant ? I feel quite frustrated about his comments. It's like he comes there just to tell you "wow man you did that… hmm…", and when you ask a bit more about it, he just gives the smallest hint possible… Don't know what's up with this guy. Isn't the point of SO to help each other out ? Anyways, I would understand if you didn't, as you've already helped me quite a lot and it's not the subject. Thanks a lot either way !